# Spotify does not work with google assistant - PI 3

Tags: pi-3

I followed these instructions thoroughly on my raspberry pi 3 and whenever I say "Ok google, play spotify" the AI says "Something went wrong". I cannot figure out what went wrong in the process? Has this happened to anyone else?

P.s. whenever I start the magic mirror I am able to see the spotify logo on the screen.

Comment: Please don't use a link that we should follow to understand your question, tl;dr. Instead explain what your problem is.

Comment: Please see modified post. @Ingo